# In Eclipse program compiles, however not in terminal, conflict of imported libraries, gradle/javac

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I'm trying to run my program using a command line interface.

Accordingly, I've written a basic CLI, which you can see below:

[image]

In Eclipse, I can supply it with arguments and run it.

However, when executing the program in the terminal, it crashes with the complaint that it can't find the libraries, which are included with gradle:

[image]

Is it necessary for one to include some kind of indicator to those gradle libraries in the `-cp` when using `javac` in order to independently build and run this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because you need to specify where the jar that contains this package is, you can do this with the following command:

```
javac -cp ".;/path/to/jar/ApacheCommonsCli.jar;/path/to/otherjar.jar;" CommandLineParameters.java
```

Also, if you are using gradle, you should not use "javac", but gradle commands.

Edit: Just as a remainder, the jar path is relative to the directory that you are running javac, but you can also use absolute paths, like `"C:/example/yourjar.jar"`

Edit2: Also, for clarification: You can run this in your IDE because it takes care of managing your classpath for you. But also, if you using gradle, you should specify your dependencies (jars) in your gradle file, and build it from there. See Gradle documentation for more detail.